# php error_log not writing all lines

Tags: php, error-log

Im developing a REST api in php and im using error_log function to write in a custom file the logs of my app.
Everything was working just fine, the logs are being written in the selected file, with the format i wanted, etc.
Testing the methods one by one all are working perfectly. But when a client does multiple requests to a method the log starts missing lines.
The api works fine and does all the tasks is requested, but the log seems like cant keep up writing the lines.

Not all lines are missing, and not the same ones. Its like php is skiping some lines randomly.

Sorry for my bad english, not my first language.

Thanks in advance for your help!

edit: I tried using shell_exec with an echo to the file but is the same result.

Comment: id suspect your problem is that one of contention...multiple writes to the same file at the same time...what does your code look like

Comment: Its hard to copy the whole code, every line of the log is written by the same function, but the function feeds from multiple files The function takes some parameters such as user, ip, ssid format them in a line and then does 
`error_log($formatedLine,3,LOCAL_LOG_FILE);`

If the writting is being done by php should the os handle that? If not how can I?

I tried saving in a session all lines and then a subprocess run a foreach and print, that way works but i went from 200ms response to 1.5 secs